# Checking permission for another user on Linux

Tags: bash, permissions

Is there a way to know the permissions for a given user (which is not the current user) for a specific file on Linux?

My question assume not switching user with `su`.

Comment: The requirement to avoid switching to the user's account is problematic; I don't think there is a good way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

This commands return 0, if youruser can read (-r), write (-w) or execute (-x) file or it returns 1 if youruser can't read, write or execute.

```
sudo -u youruser test -r /path/to/file
sudo -u youruser test -w /path/to/file
sudo -u youruser test -x /path/to/file
```

Comment: It does nothing on my system (Debian 11 without GUI)

Comment: check this command: sudo -u youruser test -r /path/to/file | echo $?

output of this command = exit code ( 0 or 1)

Comment: Can you vote for my answer if it helps you? @Fifi